# Are there any python libraries to help test external python scripts

Tags: python, testing

I'd like to test some python scripts.

Are there any python libraries to help test external system behaviors(running scripts, testing the contents of external files, managing input/output files, and similar actions).

Also I tried making the scripts more api like to allow imports rather then calling it directly for more unit test like tests. Changes include making scripts easier to run interactively(factor lots of stuff into functions/module values and make it less procedural, add parameter to silence stdout, passing optional args to main) also serializing results in addition to the usual output formats(even though the functions to generate the output files have a medium amount of logic in them)).

Is this a good strategy or is it better to attempt to test scripts by running them blackbox style and examining output.

Comment: You want to have a python testing-framework, in a black-box style to test alien programs like shell-scripts, c-programms etc.? Defining the enviroment and input, executing the blackbox-unit and interpreting the output/enviroment change?

Answer (score 0):

**Test library**

I'll go ahead and suggest [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) *(even though it's the top Google hit for "python unit testing" and you probably already know of it)*.  It's a very nice, easy to use, feature-ful library for unit testing.

**Test strategy**

Writing testable code is *hard*.  Testing things like side-effects, environments, and file output can take the **unit** right out of **unit test**.

What I typically try to do is structure the code so that as little of it as possible does I/O or other nasty things.  Then all of that code can usually be straightforwardly unit-tested.

For the parts that are hard to break into units, such as the command-line interface, I test for file output etc.

**Conclusion**

- use unit tests as much as possible
- otherwise, use black-box tests
- constantly refactor code to make writing unit tests easier & more effective